# why it doesn't work when I want to replace text by using hash keys& join function?

Tags: regex, perl

I wrote perl program like this :

```
#program1
$sentence = "dog cat";
%replacememts = ("dog" => "wolf","cat" => "tiger");
($val = $sentence) =~ s/(join "|",keys %replacements)/$replacements{$1}/g;
print "$val\n";
```

It will print **"dog cat"** . It  is not the answer I want.
But when added anonymous array & dereference array  like this:

```
#program2
$sentence = "dog cat";
%replacememts = ("dog" => "wolf","cat" => "tiger");
($val = $sentence) =~ s/(@{[join "|",keys %replacements]})/$replacements{$1}/g;
print "$val\n";
```

It will print **"wolf tiger"**. It is the answer I want. Why? What is different  between the program1 and program2? someone can tell me,thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for one thing you're defining `%replacememts` and are trying to use `%replacements`. This is why you *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write, without exception. You will then need to declare each of your variables with `my` as late as possible (don't just put a big block of declarations at the top)

Ultimately, you have the right idea but the first parameter to a substitution must be a regex pattern. It will interpolate Perl variables, which is why it worked when you used an array, but you can't just use an arbitrary Perl expression

You need to build your regex pattern into a variable and use that variable in the substitution. Like this. It's also much clearer this way

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $sentence = 'dog cat';

my %replacements = ( dog => 'wolf', cat => 'tiger' );

my $re = join '|', keys %replacements;

(my $val = $sentence) =~ s/($re)/$replacements{$1}/g;

print "$val\n";
```

#### output

```
wolf tiger
```

Comment: I got it~Thanks for your explanation!!